# Sort result is Different between command line & text edit(vim)

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, grep

I'm newbie in shell scripts (command-line).
Usually, I type single-line commands only, but, today I get different results from command line sort & text edit sort.

Short, I want to know why command-line "sort" is different from vim's ":sort".

## Question & my situation details.

I have under sample log(text) file like under.

```
// log.txt
2021-04-12 10:00:00 [USER1000] login
2021-04-12 10:01:00 [USER1100] login
2021-04-12 10:02:00 [USER1010] login
2021-04-12 10:03:00 [USER1000] logout
2021-04-12 10:04:00 [USER1000] login
2021-04-12 10:05:00 [USER2000] login
2021-04-12 10:06:00 [USER1000] logout
2021-04-12 10:07:00 [USER1100] logout
2021-04-12 10:08:00 [USER1000] login
...
```

I want to know who and how many times "login" in one day.

So, I use `cat`, `grep`, `sort`, `uniq` for this.

```sh
cat log.txt | grep "login" | grep -o "\[USER....\]" | sort | uniq -c | sort > login.txt
```

I think it return perfect result, but it's sequence was different.

### Under Step is what I expected

- 1st, `cat log.txt` print all of them.

```
2021-04-12 10:00:00 [USER1000] login
2021-04-12 10:01:00 [USER1100] login
2021-04-12 10:02:00 [USER1010] login
2021-04-12 10:03:00 [USER1000] logout
2021-04-12 10:04:00 [USER1000] login
2021-04-12 10:05:00 [USER2000] login
2021-04-12 10:06:00 [USER1000] logout
2021-04-12 10:07:00 [USER1100] logout
2021-04-12 10:08:00 [USER1000] login
```

- 2nd, `grep "login"` filter "login" only

```
2021-04-12 10:00:00 [USER1000] login
2021-04-12 10:01:00 [USER1100] login
2021-04-12 10:02:00 [USER1010] login
2021-04-12 10:04:00 [USER1000] login
2021-04-12 10:05:00 [USER2000] login
2021-04-12 10:08:00 [USER1000] login
```

- 3rd, for group per user, use `grep -o`.

```
[USER1000]
[USER1100]
[USER1010]
[USER1000]
[USER2000]
[USER1000]
```

- 4th, for use `uniq -c`, `sort` all of "login" texts.

```
[USER1000]
[USER1000]
[USER1000]
[USER1010]
[USER1100]
[USER2000]
```

- 5th, `uniq -c` for group every texts.

```
3 [USER1000]
1 [USER1010]
1 [USER1100]
1 [USER2000]
```

- 6th, `sort` one more for find-out who login very much.

> This step, I append real-case
> Not Related with upper cases

```
  1 [USER1000]
 11 [USER1001]
  2 [USER1002]
237 [USER1003]
  4 [USER1005]
```

---

---

It looks like sort by text not number.
so, I change bash command

```sh
# cat log.txt | grep "login" | grep -o "\[USER....\]" | sort | uniq -c | sort > login.txt
cat log.txt | grep "login" | grep -o "\[USER....\]" | sort | uniq -c > login.txt
vim login.txt
# in vim, :sort returns result what I want (sort by number)
```

There's no problem, but I just want to know "why different".
Can I solve this problem with command-line `sort` too?

---

---

I append My Test Code Picture because of comments.

When I wrote this Question, I get right result with vim `:sort` command.

[image: What I do with VIM]

All Test Results are under.

`sort -n` makes me result what I want.

[image]

Comment: This question makes no sense for several reasons: 1. Vim's `:sort` and your shell's `short` are just different implementations of the concept of "command for sorting lines of text". You may come across various other implementations in other contexts. This is a non-issue. 2. You don't even show what you did in Vim or its output so we can't compare it with what you did in your shell and therefore can't explain any difference. 3. The commands you show and their output don't match.

Comment: 1. I just want to know is it possible return same result with command-line `sort` Not split concept. 2. I explain it comments what I did in Vim. `:sort`. Obviously. 3. My logfile size was too big, so for make short question, I split my log.txt and Obviously explain in 6th step.

Comment: I don't know `:sort` in English like insert mode, visual mode, etc. If you don't understand, sorry for that point. @romainl

Comment: 1. Then show the two outputs so that people can compare them. 2. Don't explain, show. 3. Your logfile size is irrelevant. Your 4th step can't produce the text under it. Sort your mess.

Comment: I append picture that I tested includes all of `log.txt`. I hope that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Short, I want to know why command-line "sort" is different from vim's ":sort".

The vim `:sort` command rely on the sort function of a library used by vim. You probably have numerical sort set by default for this one, as you can see with the `:help sort` feedback :

```
 The details about sorting depend on the library function used.  There
 is no guarantee that sorting obeys the current locale.  You will have
 to try it out. Vim does do a "stable" sort.
 
 The sorting can be interrupted, but if you interrupt it too late in
 the process you may end up with duplicated lines.  This also depends
 on the system library function used.
```

You can use the OS sort command instead with `:%!sort` to retrieve the 'same' sort order than the OS command.

To sort numerically with the OS command, use the -n option :

```
cat log.txt | grep "login" | grep -o "\[USER....\]" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: Perfectly worked. I append this result with picture. Thank you and Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It is much easier to use this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '$NF == "login" {++freq[$(NF-1)]} END {for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' log.txt
[USER2000] 1
[USER1000] 3
[USER1100] 1
[USER1010] 1
```

If you want to sort the output then use:

```sh
awk '$NF == "login" {++freq[$(NF-1)]} END {for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' log.txt | sort
[USER1000] 3
[USER1010] 1
[USER1100] 1
[USER2000] 1
```

**awk References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: For explain, I type all of `log.txt` by hands. May I ask what means `$NF`, `login`? `NF` means length of string(5)?

Comment: `$NF` is last field and `$(NF-1)` is (last-1)th field in an input record. `$NF == "login"` is a condition that let's it execute next action block when last field is `login`.

Comment: I have added couple of online awk references in answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to run for test.

Comment: I like it how you say that it is much easier, show some code that hacks the planet and then add two awk tutorials at the end ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/\[[^]]*/) && /login/{
  arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)]++
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/\[[^]]*/) && /login/{        ##Using match function to match from [ to till ] here and checking if line has login in it.
  arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)]++   ##Creating arr with index of matched regex sub string.
}
END{                                   ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in arr){                     ##Starting a for loop for traversing through arr elements.
    print key,arr[key]                 ##Printing key and its value here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```